# Will a query from Organization ever return more than one row?

Tags: schema

I'm curious.  Is it possible for the query below to return more than one row?  Do Divisions somehow create multiple Organization rows within an org?

```
SELECT Id, Division
FROM Organization
```

Comment: Bottom of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way Organization will ever return more than one row is if you're logged in to the core Salesforce orgs (e.g. org 62, the org that salesforce.com employees log in to), and then only if you have permission to query customer orgs. As a customer, your query will always return exactly one row, never more or less.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting to learn about the special powers of internal Salesforce orgs.

Comment: I see that at times on sfdx org status command and it errors out because of SingleRecordQuery_MultipleRecords @sfdcfox

Comment: @jini If you can get a reliable reproduction, that should be reported. It shouldn't be possible to have more than one org in an org.

Comment: Yup. Opening a SF support case for our org. It basically broke our build pipeline etc as we query for org status using the command.